# use std::vector<char> in C++/cLi

Tags: c++, command-line-interface, marshalling

I have a function that return std::vector

when I test it, this is not correct

```
data is vector<char>
std::string myString= std::string(begin(data), end(data));
String^ result = marshal_as<String^>(myString);
return result;
```

Is this convert correct?
what can I convert my vector char? what to?

Comment: oh, do you know about marshaling? cli? clr? this for convert std::Vector<char> to string (I want use this cli in C#)

Comment: try a "marshal_as<String^>(myString.c_str());

Comment: @AntoineMorrier  I try "marshal_as<String^>(myString.c_str()); but is not correct

Comment: @zneak in this post I use std::Vector<char> not string, string is very easy

Comment: @JackD, your post converts the vector to a string. What's the problem then?

Comment: @zneak I use a RSA, for example when I get privateKey is array of byte or char ant no string